# awk command to parse file seperated by new lines

Tags: awk, newline

My input file is as follows:

```
OS ABI

   UNIX - System V

CPU Class

   64-bit

Persistence (user)

   No

File type 

   ELF 32-bit MSB executable, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version 
   (SYSV),statically linked, not   stripped,32-bit MSB executable, 
   PowerPC or cisco 4500, version (SYSV),statically linked, not stripped

CPU Type

  PowerPC
```

I want output as:

```
OS ABI UNIX - System V
CPU CLASS 64-bit
Persistence (user) No
File Type ELF 32-bit MSB executable, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version (SYSV),statically linked, not   stripped,32-bit MSB executable, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version (SYSV),statically linked, not stripped 
CPU Type PowerPC
```

Please suggest script/ command using awk which can output the desired result? The problem comes when we have to parse multiple lines as shown in Field 5. I also wish to count number of lines in each field Like : Field 1 has one line, Field 5 has 2 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it for you:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}
     !/^[[:blank:]]/{printf "%s" OFS, $0; next}
     { gsub(/(^|\n)[[:blank:]]+/,OFS) }1' file
```

This solution will only remove spacing at the beginning of the even blocks. This in contrary to other solutions where all spacing is replaced by a single one.

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT:*** Since OP changed the Input_file so adding one more solution here as per new samples.

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '
{
  gsub(/\n+/,OFS)
}
FNR%2==0{
  print value,$0
  next
}
{
  value=$0
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '     ##Setting RS(record separator) as NULL and setting FS(field separator) as new line.
{
  gsub(/\n+/,OFS)             ##Globally substituting one or more lines occurrence with space here.
}
FNR%2==0{                     ##Checking condition if line number is even then do following.
  print value,$0              ##Printing value and current line here.
  next                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  value=$0                    ##Assigning current line value to variable value here.
}
' Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with provided samples.

```
awk '
NF && /^Field/{
  if(field_value && value){
    print field_value,value
  }
  value=""
  field_value=$0
  next
}
NF{
  value=(value?value OFS:"")$0
}
END{
  if(field_value && value){
    print field_value,value
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Another `awk` variant:

```
awk '/^[^ \t]/{if (p != "") print p; p=$0} 
/^[ \t]/{sub(/^[ \t]+/, ""); p = p " " $0} END{print p}' file
```

```
OS ABI UNIX - System V
CPU Class 64-bit
Persistence (user) No
File type  ELF 32-bit MSB executable, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version  (SYSV),statically linked, not   stripped,32-bit MSB executable,  PowerPC or cisco 4500, version (SYSV),statically linked, not stripped
CPU Type PowerPC
```

Or if you can use `perl` then use this one-liner:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(?:\h*\R+)+\h+/ /g; s/\R(?:\h*\R)+/\n/g' file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v RS= 'NR%2{p=$0; next} {$0=p $0; $1=$1} 1' file
OS ABI UNIX - System V
CPU Class 64-bit
Persistence (user) No
File type ELF 32-bit MSB executable, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version (SYSV),statically linked, not stripped,32-bit MSB executable, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version (SYSV),statically linked, not stripped
CPU Type PowerPC
```